# How to pass ActiveRecord model class to Resque

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, resque

Let's say I have the following Resque job:

```
class Archive
  @queue = :file_serve

  def self.perform(repo_id, branch = 'master')
    repo = Repository.find(repo_id)
    repo.create_archive(branch)
  end
end
```

What if I wanted to make this more generic by passing an object id and the object's class so that I can do something like this:

```
class Archive
  @queue = :file_serve

  def self.perform(object_class, object_id, branch = 'master')
    object = object_class.find(object_id)
    object.create_archive(branch)
  end
end
```

This doesn't work, obviously, and I don't have a sense for what I *should* be doing, so if anyone can give some guidance, that would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would pass the name of the class to the job, rather than the class itself. Then you could call `constantize` on the name to get the class back, and call `find` on it. eg.

```
def self.perform(class_name, object_id, branch = 'master')
  object = class_name.constantize.find(object_id)
  object.create_archive(branch)
end
```